# How to wrap text on a curved path with perspective?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I need to replace some text in a photograph where the curved path is on a plane not perpendicular to the camera. I am using PS/AI CS4.

This example is actually harder than the one I'm working on, since my text is on a flat plane :

[image: Illustrative example; not the actual image]

I have a feeling the solution involves Photoshop's 3D features. Bonus points if you can do it without rasterizing the text.

Comment: can you show the PLANE ?

Comment: @Jack I think the ["plane" here is mathematical](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(mathematics)) and which shouldn't be, in this case, [perpendicular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular) i.e. not forming a right angle (90 °) to the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the Warp Text>Arc Tool in this particular case.

Here's an image showing the results:

[image: warp text - arc example]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not yet entirely clear about the question, but if I understand you correctly, here are the steps:

1: Create the curve as a path.

2: Use the "Type on a Path" tool to create the text.

3: Convert to a Smart Object.

4: Edit > Transform > Perspective.

Since you're trying to overlay this on an existing image, you may have to add:

0: Trace the curve in the image.

00: On a new layer, stroke the path with a thin pencil.

000: Use 3d > 3d Postcard from Layer to adjust this curve until it looks actually perpendicular to the image plane. Trace this curve as Step 1.

In either case, you end up with editable text, because it's in a Smart Object.

Comment: By overlaying I mean I am going to erase the original text first, like changing "Coors" to "Corona" in the example above.

Comment: It wasn't the overlay bit (I'm assuming you have that well in hand), but what perspective transform you need. I'd do the Coors > Corona conversion the way I described (plus appropriate layer styles, of course). We tend to forget that most simple "3D" transforms can be accomplish quite simply with perspective tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

How far away from perpendicular do you mean?
Here's a generic "angle" that is basically pushing the upper right corner forward and down a little, but things like this is hard to describe in words so its probably best if you laid down a sketch of what exactly you mean.

[image]

I also agree this would probably be better over at graphic design.

Comment: The problem with that is that the text is perpendicular to the path; it would not look like this is real life. I want to maintain perspective. Did you simply create a path and put some text on it?