# Adding texts with 3d perspective

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, text-on-path

I am new to AI and trying to write some texts on the buttons of the keyboard in the attached image:[image: keyboard with buttons]

I would like to add few letters on the buttons with missing letters in such a way they look similar to letters on other buttons.

I tried using solutions like 3D rotation as described [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15209/add-3d-perspective-to-a-vectorized-text) and warp text technique explained [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/how-to-wrap-text-on-a-curved-path-with-perspective). But none of them helped me...could anyone please guide me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one's a super-quick one - so I didn't make it *perfect* but just close enough to demonstrate the concept.

First, after placing your image as a backdrop (put it on its own layer and lock that layer) with nothing selected you choose the **Eyedropper Tool** from the toolbar. Click the eyedropper onto one of your letterforms: once the colour shows it's picked up that tone, save a swatch and call it something like "key letters".

[image]

Using the basic **Type Tool**, type your chosen letter on a new layer, select our letter and apply your "key letter" colour swatch.

[image]

Go up to the menu above, and choose **Object>Envelope Distort>Make with Mesh**

[image]

Choose a 1 x 1 mesh to make your life easy, and use the white **Direct Select Arrow** to move the individual anchor points to basically match the perspective distortion of the key rectangle.

Move the anchor handles to make the sides of the mesh as straight-line as you can... once you've done one letter to your satisfaction, move a copy to the next key, double click on it and you can edit the letter and the envelope will be retained - so you're home free!

My quickie ended up looking like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for wonderful explanation. @Danielillo was a simple and straightforward but perspective view could not be obtained as it look awkward when two letters are there. Your solution was elegant and just produced what I wanted. Activating Direct Selection Tool (I learnt it is easy by shortcut A and then double click to activate) and making boundary straight was challenging. I learnt by adjusting handle coinciding with boundary makes side as straight.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

On your text, make a 3D rotate from menu Effect → 3D → Rotate:

[image: 3D rotate]